# What type should I use for empty object?

Tags: typescript

I set the return type of the function below to `{}`, and eslint gave an error(Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".).

OK, I understood what this error means because return type `{}` allows me to return a value of other types.

So if I want to return only an empty object, what type should be used as the return type?

```
function a(): {} {
  return {};
  // return 1; // NOT ALLOWED
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context? A function returning an empty object doesn't seem terribly useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can make use of the [never type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

`never` is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns.

So here with the `EmptyObject` type it is saying that all properties can only be never.

No type is assignable to `never` so creating an object would not be possible which causes the object to be empty.

**EDIT:**

Not sure what is the use case for this though.

```
type EmptyObject = {
    [K in never] : never
}

function a(): EmptyObject {
  return {};
}
```

Comment: I really don't think this is intentional use of `never` and you won't be able to add anything to the object. I guess it's hard to say, with no real use case given here. If OP really wants to return only an empty object, then this will work

Comment: Yes that is true. I am still waiting for OP to clarify why this sort of functionality is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not correct in the assumption that the typescript compiler will prevent numbers or any other primitive type to be assigned to `{}`.

```js
const test1: {} = 'hello'
const test2: {} = 123
const test3: {} = false
const test4: {} = { foo: 'bar' }
const test5: {} = [1, 2, 3]
const test6: {} = null          // Error if strictNullChecks is set to true in tsconfig
const test7: {} = undefined     // Error if strictNullChecks is set to true in tsconfig
```

- [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CMAuGBvAvjAvDA5ABbwA2JI+AsAFCiSwLQBMaWuMSTAzDXdHIihdW2PADMAhiQjxe4foygAWEe3QwxIEGnwAjCQCd8MTHPoDoAVlV4A2kgA0MJk64BdMwsEA2GzDAArmSeDIIA7H4BYAAm8GIAlmDw0UA)

It's may also be interesting to learn the difference between `object` and `Object`: [Typing objects in TypeScript](https://2ality.com/2020/01/typing-objects-typescript.html)

### Index Signatures

```js
type GenericObject = { [key: string]: any };

function a(): GenericObject  {
  return {};
  // return 1; // NOT ALLOWED
}
```

Key of all properties is any string and the type of all is `any`

- [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgeQEYCsJuCgF4oBvKAbQGsIQAuKAZ2FXgHMBdBgQ3hCgC+AbgBQIgDYRCAWxAA1bqm5ZJARgZxEqTLnyESqoVAD0xqABVw0AOTwArtKzJrUFIyjwA9oW6NGKNnhlSShgT1CrKGtyaloGZlZOHj4jAWsJKShZBSUVCAAmDQRkdGw8AmIo5TRrI1MLSOsElHYXNw9vKF9-QODoMIjIKJiaeiYWFqSulMF0yRl5RRQ+gGYirVLdCpJSARMzDABpDIWc5byAFnWSnXL9MiDpCAZrAEcAd2RQaz3TI6A)
- [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures)

### Utility Type

There is also a broad variety of utility types for these kind of problems but I personally haven't used them.

- [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)